# Laptop fails to suspend (deep)

Tags: suspend

I've been struggling with suspend issues for quite a while now.

I'm running a XPS15 9570 with 4.19.93-1-lts. My system fails to enter deep sleep and outputs this error:

"PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected"

I did a bunch of research and in all the posts I've found the error is accompanied by an error message indicating which device fails. In my case there is no device specific error or any other message indicating the reason.

```
Jan 10 16:06:39 [host] kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Jan 10 16:06:40 [host] kernel: PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Jan 10 16:06:40 [host] kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Jan 10 16:06:40 [host] kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Jan 10 16:06:40 [host] kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Jan 10 16:06:40 [host] kernel: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Jan 10 16:06:40 [host] kernel: wlp58s0: deauthenticating from fc:ec:da:ab:2f:c3 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Jan 10 16:06:40 [host] kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Jan 10 16:06:40 [host] kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Jan 10 16:06:40 [host] kernel: PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
```

More journalctl: https://pastebin.com/8kaFhfZQ

I would be very grateful if anyone had some pointers on how to debug this.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas... Make sure you `umount` network shares. `sudo fuser /media/<mountlocation>` will show you which processes to stop if you can't unmount them, and `umount -f -l /media/<mountlocation>` will force an unmount.

Also disable Wake-on-LAN:

```
$ sudo ethtool -s eno1 wol d
```